# Conditional rendering in angular

Tags: angular, templates

In all my components I have 3 differents templates according to the data state:
Show loader if data is loading
Show error message if there is an error when fetching data.
Show 'no data' if there is no data
Otherwise show the component itself

For now I have a switch case in all of my components.
I would like to move that logic in one place in order to keep my code as DRY as possible.

What would be the angular way to do it?

Comment: Share please example of template code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by using a structural directive, that looks like so

Here is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j5waia?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appDeafultView]'
})
export class DeafultViewDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() appDeafultView: Observable<string>;
  stateSub;

  factoryMap = {
    error: () => {
      const factory2 = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ErrorComponet);
      this.viewContainer.createComponent(factory2);
    },
    loading: () => {
      const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(LoadingComponent);
      this.viewContainer.createComponent(factory);
    },
    loaded: () => {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    }
  };

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.stateSub = this.appDeafultView.subscribe(state => {
      console.log(state);
      this.viewContainer.clear();
      this.factoryMap[state]();
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.stateSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

My idea is that based on observable, describing the state of request you can show different templates, where the `ErrorComponent` and `LoadingComponent` are predefined and in the case your data has been loaded successfully you will show the element on which you have attached your directive.

The usage of this directive will look like so

```html
<p *appDeafultView="mix$">
  Content loaded
</p>
```

Where `mix$` will be an observable that will resolve as either `loading`, `error` or `loaded`, and based on that the appropriate thing will be rendered.